# PDO does not throw 1062 when inserting value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

This is my table :

table name : tags

column name : tag

- #classical
- #dnb
- #jazz
- #music
- #reggae
- #rnb
- #rock

these are type `VARCHAR(255)` and they are *unique.*
When i try to insert `"#music"` from phpmyadmin, i get the expected result :

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '#music' for key 'tag'
```

However, when i try to do this via php, using this piece of code :

```
...

        try{
            $music = "#music";
            $sql = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES (?)" );
            $sql->execute(array($music));
            $firephp->log("inserted");  

        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            if($e->getCode() == 1062)
                $firephp->log("1062");  
            else
                $firephp->log("else");
        }
```

firephp outputs "inserted" to the console, and it does not jump to catch block. Moreover, nothing is inserted to the table. When i try to add a non-unique value, it adds it to the table though.

What am i missing here? Why does PDO not throw an exception?

Comment: Add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if it yields anything and if you're not using that already.

Comment: wow, it actually catched it, but somehow `$e->getCode() == 1062` returned false

Comment: I take it that it didn't insert it?

Comment: What was the value of `$e->getCode()` and `$e->getMessage()`?

Comment: yeah, it did not insert anything. But shouldn't it go to the first if, since it is a duplicate entry error? @Barmar let me check

Comment: Try a different method `VALUES (:music)` then `$sql->bindParam(':music', $music); $sql->execute();` see if that makes it kick in. Or, is the problem in trying to execute the catch?

Comment: @Barmar value of `$e->getCode()`  is `23000`  and value of  `$e->getMessage()`  is   `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '#rock' for key 'tag'` if i use 23000, rather then 1062, would it be OK? i thought duplicate err no was 1062, why is it 23000 i wonder. @Fred checking it out

Comment: OK, got it, i think i should believe in "searching" more. Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774943/check-for-duplicate-entry-vs-use-pdo-errorinfo-result